# Same variable type (String) but not work when use

Tags: php, arrays, string, date

10-01-2014 ===> means 10 jan 2014

i have source code like this:

```
foreach($report_data['summary'] as $key=>$row) {

  $substrdate=substr($row['payment_type'],-16); //i have check the result is 10-01-2014 & 11-01-2014
  $stringvar = '10-01-2014';
  $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', $stringvar);

    $summary_data_row[] = array('data'=>'<span style="color:'.$color.'">'.$date->format('Y-m-d').'</span>', 'align'=>'right');
    $summary_data_row[] = array('data'=>'<span style="color:'.$color.'">'.$row['comment'].'</span>', 'align'=>'right');
   }//end of foreach
```

it runs well '10-01-2014' become '2014-01-10' in string type as what i want ..until i substitute variable $stringvar with $substrdate which has same value -> '10-01-2014'  , syntax $date->format('Y-m-d') makes my program blank page. no error shown in logs.

pls help

Comment: I don't get it. Your code should not work: `substr` cannot have a negative index as argument.

Comment: What are you trying to acheive?

Comment: @AdrienCadet yes, it can.

Comment: @Gerald Schneider Oh interesting. So what is the outcome?

Comment: @AdrienCadet Why don't you [look it up](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php)?

Answer (score 1):

I also faced the same problem. and my solution was the following code.

```
$stringvar  = '12-01-2014';
$date= date('Y-m-d',strtotime(str_replace("-","/",$stringvar)));
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
//$stringvar = '10-01-2014';
//$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', $stringvar);
```

Use this instead of above one

```
$stringvar = '10-01-2014';
 $date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($stringvar));
```

Comment: hi the result is 1st January, 1970 not as what i expected 2014-01-10

Comment: hi i have update your solution in my program. the result is 1970-01-01 it has different date with my input 10-01-2014. why it can change the date?

Comment: $stringvar=substr($row['payment_type'],-16); // result is 10-01-2014 
$summary_data_row[] = array('data'=>'<span style="color:'.$color.'">'.date("Y-m-d", strtotime($stringvar)).'</span>', 'align'=>'right'); //result is 1970-01-10

Comment: `$stringvar=substr($row['payment_type'],-16); 
s$summary_data_row[] = array('data'=>'<span style="color:'.$color.'">'.date("Y-m-d", strtotime('10-01-2014')).'</span>', 'align'=>'right'); `
check this may be ur value return some what wrong answer its returns right  ?

Comment: i have done what u say and it shows correctly as i want 2014-01-10 :(  but i am confused, i have echo $stringvar=substr($row['payment_type'],-16); the result is 10-01-2014 but why when i put $stringvar to your code it changed to 1970-01-10

Comment: what is $stringvar=substr($row['payment_type'],-16); ?

Comment: what result returns ?

Comment: hi   result is 10-01-2014

Comment: sure it will return 2014-01-10

Comment: Glizzweb but return is not 2014-01-10 when i use substring function. do you know the problem

Comment: for wat purpose u are using sub string ?